# How to unfold application.inputbox that chosen?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list, and from the list the user chooses some cells. Not a range, just random cells (like: A8, A2, A5..). I can not unfold this data, let's say in a message box.

```
Sub ex81()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Application.InputBox("choose cells:", Type:=8)
    ca = Application.CountA(r)
    For i = 1 To ca:
        MsgBox r(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

in this code if A2, A5, A7 are chosen, it'll show me A2, A3, A4 - he knows right only the first cell and how much cells which are chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Include an error handling for the case the user presses the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button.
2. Use a `For Each` loop to loop through all chosen cells.

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ex81()
    Dim ChosenCells As Range
    On Error Resume Next 'next line throws error if user presses cancel
    Set ChosenCells = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="choose cells:", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0 'always re-activate error handling

    If ChosenCells Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'exit if user pressed cancel

    Dim iCell As Range
    For Each iCell In ChosenCells.Cells
        MsgBox iCell.Address
    Next iCell
End Sub
```